# (Python) Running a function for all objects in a list

Tags: python, class

I have a class called Wall, with a function called draw, which draws a line on a pygame screen. i would like to be able run the draw function for all wall objects without having to go back to the draw section.
heres the code for the class

```
class Wall():

def __init__(self, Pos1, Pos2):
    self.name = self
    self.Pos1 = Pos1
    self.Pos2 = Pos2
    print("wall initalized")

def draw(self):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, white, self.Pos1, self.Pos2, 3)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, self.Pos1, 5)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, self.Pos2, 5)
    print("wall drawn")
```

Comment: Your posted code has incorrect indentation, and lacks the expected usage attempts.  Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  It's not entirely clear what functionality you want; "the draw section" is not a concept that appears in your code, as you do not have "sections".  I suggest that you read up on loops and the `apply` method.  Then make a valid coding attempt.  If you have trouble, post *that* state of affairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all the wall objects you can do the following:

```
for wall in list_of_walls:
    wall.draw()
```